# Unexpected behavior in pandas mad() with groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I create a dataframe:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

If I do most statistics on a grouped version of that dataframe, they come out as expected:

```
In [2]: df.groupby('a').median()
Out[2]: 
   b
a   
1  2
2  5
```

But when I calculate the median absolute deviation (mad), I get an extra column 'a', which is all zeros:

```
In [3]: df.groupby('a').mad()
Out[3]: 
   a         b
a             
1  0  0.666667
2  0  0.666667
```

The mad() function seems to work fine on a normal dataframe, just not on a grouped on. Unless this is a feature, not a bug, and I just don't understand it. Thoughts?

Comment: maybe not important, but just for clarification, pandas mad() is not median absolute deviation, but mean absolute deviation. from the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mad.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, slated to be fixed for 0.14 (releasing soon), see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5610). The bug is that non-cythonized routines are calling `apply` rather than ``agg` effectively.

work-around is to do:

```
df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: x.mad())
```

Comment: what if I want to use it with df.groupby(['a','b']).agg([mean,std,mad]) ?? mean and std are returned but mad returns an error.. As of today , the version of pandas is 0.16.0

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, MAD is the mean absolute deviaton , not the median AD!